# Access vba random function not working

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a sub that is supposed to take a number of assignments (this number changes daily) and assign them to 7 associates.  There are some conditions to this:

If the # of assignment is less than 7, it assigns all of them to a random associate.
If the # is divisible by 7, it assigns an equal number to each.
If it is not divisible by 7, it assigns equally and then gives the remainder to a random associate.

The problem is the random part.  I really don't understand how random works in vba, or at least it seems like it should be super easy, but it's not (maybe).  But I have this written and it's not working.  `(Associates(Int(Rnd() * 7) + 1))`.  Here is my relevant code:

Earlier in the sub I create an array of the associates and I use some dcounts to get the total assignments for that day:

```
Dim Associates(6) As Integer
    Associates(0) = 4687 'Anita
    Associates(1) = 4247 'Alberto
    Associates(2) = 2167 'Jeff
    Associates(3) = 4334 'Lisa
    Associates(4) = 4441 'Carrie
    Associates(5) = 2052 'Bobby
    Associates(6) = 4657 'Simona
'
Dim Person As Variant
'
TotalPop = DCount("LNo", "qry_PT_Assign")
FractionPop = Int(TotalPop / 7)
LeftPop = TotalPop - (FractionPop * 7)
'
```

and then I try to actually assign them.

```
        'Assign to Associates
        If TotalPop < 7 Then
            DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE tbl_Assignments SET AudTellerID = " & (Associates(Int(Rnd() * 7) + 1)) & " WHERE AudTellerID IS NULL"
        ElseIf LeftPop = 0 Then
            For Each Person In Associates
                DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE tbl_Assignments SET AudTellerID = " & Person & " WHERE LNo IN (SELECT TOP " & FractionPop & " LNo FROM tbl_Assignments WHERE AudTellerID Is Null)"
            Next
        Else
            For Each Person In Associates
                DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE tbl_Assignments SET AudTellerID = " & Person & " WHERE LNo IN (SELECT TOP " & FractionPop & " LNo FROM tbl_Assignments WHERE AudTellerID Is Null)"
            Next
            DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE tbl_Assignments SET AudTellerID = " & (Associates(Int(Rnd() * 7) + 1)) & " WHERE AudTellerID IS NULL"
        End If
```

Comment: Which bit is not working? The VBA help says:  Before calling Rnd, use the Randomize statement without an argument to initialize the random-number generator with a seed based on the system timer.

To produce random integers in a given range, use this formula:

Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)
 

Here, upperbound is the highest number in the range, and lowerbound is the lowest number in the range.  As your Associates array is from 0 to 6, then shouldn't you be using Int(7 * Rnd() + 0)

Comment: I'd probably try generating the random number first, assign it to a variable, and then pass the variable into `Associates()`. That way you'll be able to see what number is actually being generated

Comment: @kaybee99 by pass the variable do you mean add it to the array?  so, Associates(7) = (Associates(Int(Rnd() * 7) + 1))?

Comment: @ChipsLetten maybe that's all it is, I will try this

Comment: kaybee99 means store the value in an integer, e.g. `randomNum = Int(Rnd() * 7) + 1` and then use `Associates(randomNum)` because then you can use `Debug.Print randomNum` to see what number the code produced.

Comment: @ChipsLetten I see, i will try that.  for the record, and I'm sorry I didn't state this before, but right now it always assigns to Bobby (2052)

Comment: Has the `AudTellerID ` field been set to NULL by some other process?

Comment: @ChipsLetten no, they start out unassigned (ID is null) and this is the process to assign them.  I might not need that criteria in there, but I have it in there right now, just in case

Comment: It looks like what @kaybee99 suggested is working.  I also changed it to `Int(Rnd() * 7) + 0` as per @ChipsLetten 's suggestion and I can't tell right now if that helped or did nothing, but it didn't hurt.  I'll keep testing.  Let me know if I should convert this to an answer so I can give points to whoever.  and a big thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, try generating the random number first, assign it to a variable, and then pass the variable into `Associates()`.

```
Dim rndInt as Integer

rndInt = Int(Rnd() * 7) + 1

Associates(rndInt)
```

Then as @Chips said, you can use

```
Debug.print rndInt
```

Or

```
Msgbox rndInt
```

to check its value

That way you'll be able to see what number is actually being generated

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use a negative seed that changes constantly.

So add a time dependant seed to Rnd which changes for every unique id like in this sample select query:

```
 SELECT 
   Table1.ID, 
   Table1.SomeField, 
   Table1.AnotherField, 
   Rnd(-Timer()*[ID]) AS RandomIndex 
 FROM 
   Table1
 ORDER BY 
   Rnd(-Timer()*[ID]);
```

In your code, the expression could be something like this:

```
.. " & (Associates(Int(Rnd(-Timer()*" & [ID] & ") * 7) + 1)) & " ..
```