# How to get new random rows every time from an MS-Access query?

Tags: ms-access, random, vba, records

This is a problem I faced As I have a large database of meteorological data, I want to get random rows to manipulate through a model. I used a column with a random number in the `ORDER BY` statement.
Here are my trials and their drawbacks:

1- I tried to use a column with `rnd()` function. *It returns the same number for all records!*

2- I combined the row number with the random function as: `rnd([ID])`. *It returns a new number for each record, but the whole set of numbers is repeated every time!*

3- Finally, I found the answer that I want to share with you.

Best regards for all.

Comment: There is no "real random" in IT world. Can be only pseudo-random

Comment: @J.Doe I mean a new set of random numbers. Thanks, I have changed the title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access vba random function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360646/access-vba-random-function-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use VBA to generate a new random number for every run and for each record.

Open the VBA editor, create a new module, and paste the following code:

```
Public Function GenerateRandom(Param As Long) As Double
    Randomize
    GenerateRandom = Rnd(Param)
End Function
```

Then save and close the VBA editor.

Use the `GenerateRandom([Id])` instead of `rnd([Id])` function in your work.
This may be slower, but it will ensure 100% randomization.

Hope this helps...

Comment: You don't need an external function. See link above for the duplicate question.

Comment: Dear @Gustav I reviewed the mentioned question, it does not solve the problem I mentioned, however, it uses VBA as well. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Well, read again, please. The query exactly solves your issue - which is a classic.